# How to use jprofiler find unable to GC memory

Tags: jprofiler

How can I find the data that cannot be GC
[9G is left after automatic GC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDgD9.png)

Answer (score 0):

To find out in JProfiler which objects are strongly referenced, you have to use the heap walker.

Start with the "Biggest objects" view to find single objects that retain the largest portions of the heap.